defining multiple field relationship in prisma schema

How can I assign custom Id to the room model while it's creation?

Wanted to create a schema to store a user id of two user.
Something like this:


model room {
  id             String @id @default(auto()) @map("_id") @db.ObjectId
  participant1Id String
  participant2Id String
  participants   User   @relation(fields: [participant1Id, participant2Id], references: [id, id])
}

But vscode is giving me this error:

Error validating field participant1 in model room: The relation field participant1 on model room is missing an opposite relation field on the model User. Either run prisma format or add it manually.
Error validating field participant2 in model room: The relation field participant2 on model room is missing an opposite relation field on the model User. Either run prisma format or add it manually.

and this is the error that i getting when running yarn run prisma format:
Error: Prisma schema validation - (validate wasm)
Error code: P1012
error: Field "room" is already defined on model "User".
-->  schema.prisma:23
|
22 |   room     room[]
23 |   room     room[]
|
Validation Error Count: 1
[Context: validate]
Prisma CLI Version : 5.11.0
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.

Would like to create custom ids
Would like to create a schema for a room where there are only two participants

model room {
  id             String @id @default(auto()) @map("_id") @db.ObjectId
  participant1Id String
  participant2Id String
  participants   User   @relation(fields: [participant1Id, participant2Id], references: [id, id])
}

